# Keeping track of access tokens by using oAuth 2

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api, google-oauth

I am a beginner in using Google Analytics API and I want to track the access tokens separately as they expires.

Note that I am using `server->offline` settings in the oAuth 2.0.

Comment: What do you mean by track them?  Why would you want to track expired access tokens?

Comment: @DalmTo; here ,i want to get the `access token`  and also the `refresh token` saved because after the `access token` expires it will send the `refresh token` again to the authorization server and new `refresh` and `access` tokens will be given

Comment: @DaImTo: and i want to know whether this could be done without a `clicking` event for `refresh access token` after it expires

Comment: I think that's going to depend upon how you code your application.   You should send your request if you get an unauthorized error then you simply refresh your access token and send the request again.    I normally store an expired time for my access tokens then I can make a simple test before using it if its expired I request a new one.

Comment: Your question has potential why don't you read this and try and edit your question and improve it.   http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask   Show us what you have tried and what issues or questions you may have.